# Как правильно преобразовать string в string[]?

Tags: c#, строки

Есть код, который принимает string и делит его на строки. Но проблема в том, что я не знаю, как правильно перевести из string в string[]. Вот код:

```
string[] names = gp.GetValueNames();
foreach (string valueName in names)
{
    for (int i=1; i<100; i++)
    {
        string[] folders = App.Properties.Settings.Default.Folder; // вот тут не работает перевод
        Directory.Delete((string)gp.GetValue(valueName) + folders[0], true);
    }
}
```

Comment: А зачем-то тут `string[] folders`? Можно же просто `string` сделать.

Comment: Да и в правду, не заметил, спасибо огромное!!!

Comment: @IvanDidyk если не затруднит ответьте пожалуйста. У меня в property folder заложен текст из 2-ух строчек. Почему-то когда я пытаюсь выбрать например 1-ую строку folders[1] он выводит символ, а не строку или я что-то путаю?

Comment: Покажите определение `App.Properties.Settings.Default.Folder`. Оно явно задано у вас как строка/string. А вам, судя по всему, нужна коллекция строк.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не забываем что индексация начинается с 0!!!
Первая строка под индексом 0.